# the use of javascript self invoke anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, self-invoking-function

Please see the following code blocks. Which one is the best option? Basically they are all doing the same thing

**Example 1**

```
var otherVars1
var otherVars2
var otherVars3
var valid; // create a boolean variable
// some precondition to set valid to true or false
.... 

if (valid || someRegex.test(value)) {
  ...
}
```

**Example 2**

```
var otherVars1
var otherVars2
var otherVars3

// create a function that return a boolean
function isValid() {
  ...
  return Boolean
}

if (isValid() || someRegex.test(value)) {
 ...
}
```

**Example 3**

```
var otherVars1
var otherVars2
var otherVars3

// use self-invoke anonymous function directly
if ((function() {
...
return Boolean })() || someRgex.test(value)) {
  ...
}
```

Comparing these three examples, I prefer to use self invoke anonymous function(example 3) for the following reasons

- Does not need to create unnecessary vars and allocate memory (ex1: valid, ex2: isValid)
- Keep code clean, piece by piece or module so that it is easy to manage and organize
- Self contained so that the variable outside of self invoke anonymous function does not get polluted

Please correct me if I am wrong on any of the point above and tell me what is your preference and reason?

Comment: All you really need is `if ( valid || someRegex.test(value))` the entire if/else condition that sets a boolean is uneccessary

Comment: @adeneo thanks for the replay, but valid depends some preconditions

Comment: Then use whatever you like. I think the IIFE is the least readable, but if that's what you like, go for it.

Comment: *"Keep code clean"* - including a multiline IIFE in an `if` condition isn't my idea of "clean". In my opinion option 3 is the worst one because it is the least readable.

Comment: #1 is easiest to read. #2 is good if you call isValid() multiple times.  #3 decreases clarity. Why is memory so scarce in your situation?

Comment: Just wanna see what is the best choice for all of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you can go with the `immediate invocation of function expressions` but you can avoid using them inside the `if` and you could use as below.

This will avoid unnecessary `global scope` of variable declarations, functions etc.

```
(function() {
  var otherVars1
  var otherVars2
  var otherVars3
  var valid; // create a boolean variable
  // some precondition to set valid to true or false
  .... 

  if (valid || someRegex.test(value)) {
    ...
  }

})();
```